# How to stop pycharm from searching inside virtual environment folder?

Tags: pycharm

I have a `.venv` folder inside the project root, which has a python virtual environment. When I use the search feature of Pycharm, it also shows the result from this `.venv`  folder. How can I ignore the virtual environment folder from search results?

I tried marking the directory as `Excluded`, but that didn't help.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Did you exclude the venv folder? Right-click on the `.venv` in the project tree -> Mark directory as -> Excluded.

Comment: Nope, But it is happening only for my one project. Even after marking it as excluded, it still searches in that folder.

Comment: Same here. Perhaps a bug in pycharm since 2019.

Comment: Still not working, but the other answer did work.

Comment: I had to clear the file system cache after marking venv as as excluded, after that it worked.

File > Invalidate Caches... > check "Clear file system cache..." > Invalidate and Restart

Comment: already marked as exlcuded but still see it in 'search all files' result

Answer (score 8):

I'm experiencing the same issue: Even though I've marked the `.venv` directory as excluded, its contents still show up in the "Find in Files" search results.

I've found a workaround for this, though. In my "Project Settings" I define an "Exclude files" pattern like so:

1. Open the **"Settings"** window from the **"File"** menu.
2. Find and expand the **"Project: *<your project name>*"** section on the left.
3. Under that section click the **"Project Structure"** sub-section.
4. At the bottom of the form on the right, enter `**.venv**` as the value for **"Exclude files:"**.
5. Click **"OK"** to confirm and close.

[image]

Comment: I like this approach better than the accepted answer, because this way you can also find class definitions with "Ctrl+N"

Comment: Same. Excluding in the file listing didn't work, but adding the path name in the exclude pattern for the project did work.

Comment: added `**.venv**` so and still NOT working for me

Answer (score 0):

To get the right answer out, thanks others' anwsers to this OP, the steps to get rid of .venv in find-in-files are

00 add it to `mark as exluded`

01 clear cache and restart ide

Cheers